# How to retrieve the student information from the table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

```
student table   teacher table    sports table     parents table
---------     --------------     ------------      ---------------
id  name        id  name        id  name           id    stud_id  fathername   mothername
------------   ------------    ------------        -----------------------------------------
1    S1           1     T1         1    SP1         1       1       xxxxxx       yyyyyyy
2    S2           2     T2         2    SP2         2      2        abc          aaa    
3    S3           3     T3         3    SP3 

student_teacher table               student_sports table
id    stud_id     teacher_id       id      sutd_id    sports_id
------------------------------     ------------------------------
1      1            1               1        1          1
2      1            2               2        1          2
3      1            3               3        1          3
4      2            2               4        3          2
5      2            3               5        3          3
```

How to write a query to get information of student S1 from all the table.
 For example, student S1 participated sports name, teachers name who teaching student S1, student S1 parents information. Here id in student, teacher, parent table are primary key. stud_id, teacher_id, sports_id are foreign key which refers student, teacher, sports table primary key. 
Kindly help me to get the record of Student S1 from table. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use where clause :

```
select S.name, T.name, SS.name, P.fathername, P.mothername 
from student S, teacher T, sports SS, parents P,student_teacher ST, student_sports SSP 
where S.id = ST.stud_id and T.id = ST.teacher_id and
S.id = SSP.stud_id and SS.id = SSP.sports_id and
S.id = P.stud_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution :

```
select st.name as Student, t.name as teacher, sp.name as sports, p.fathername,p.mothername from student st,teacher t,sports sp,parents p,student_teacher s_t,student_sports s_s where s_t.stud_id=st.id and s_t.teacher_id=t.id and p.stud_id=st.id and s_s.stud_id=st.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine the `student_teacher` and `student_sports` tables. There's no way to marry up which teacher taught which student for a particular sport. All we know is Student 1 participated in sports 1, 2 and 3, and was taught by teachers 1, 2 and 3. We don't know which teacher took which sport. You should have this:

```
student_sports_teacher table
+----+---------+-----------+------------+
| id | stud_id | sports_id | teacher_id |
+----+---------+-----------+------------+
|  1 |       1 |         1 |          1 |
|  2 |       1 |         2 |          2 |
|  3 |       1 |         3 |          3 |
|  4 |       2 |         1 |          2 |
|  5 |       2 |         2 |          3 |
+----+---------+-----------+------------+
```

Once you've done that you can use joins to get all your data:

```
SELECT * FROM student s
LEFT JOIN parents p ON s.id = p.stud_id
LEFT JOIN student_sports_teacher sst ON sst.stud_id = s.id
LEFT JOIN sports sp ON sp.id = sst.sports_id
LEFT JOIN teacher t ON t.id = sst.teacher_id
```

Comment: No need to use left joins.  OP is using foreign keys, so you won't have any orphaned records.

Comment: Just a habit, I always specify the join type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner join

```
     select st.name as Student, t.name as teacher, sp.name as sports, 
          p.fathername,p.mothername 
     from student st
     Inner join student_teacher as st on st s_t.stud_id=st.id 
     Inner join teacher t on s_t.teacher_id=t.id 
     Inner join parents p on p.stud_id=st.id 
     Inner join student_sports ss on  ss.stud_id=st.id;
```